# BXNUI0035E “service could not be deleted”

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to unbind & delete a Mongolabs service instance from my app in IBM Bluemix.  Unfortunately, Bluemix displays the error:

```
BXNUI0035E The 'Mongolab-cv' service could not be deleted.
```

And leaves the service allocated and bound to my app.

How do I fix this?

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoLab service was deprecated last year. Service instances created before it were not deleted, but since the service broker is not available anymore you will not be able to delete or unbind this service.

Please raise a support ticket to get this service removed from your space. 
To open a ticket check the link below:

[ibm.biz/bluemixsupport](http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport)

When opening a ticket provide your organization name, space and service name.